# Pandas data manipulation and counting on the same line

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the number of books in a dataset whose publication year is equal to or greater than 2000.
Here is the format of the column:
publication_date = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Here is my code:

```
df[int(df["publication_date"][-4: 0]) >= 2000]["publication_date"].count()
```

I am receiving error like the one below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-ed1072acfb26> in <module>
----> 1 df[int(df["publication_date"][-4: 0]) >= 2000]["publication_date"].count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in wrapper(self)
    127         if len(self) == 1:
    128             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 129         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    130 
    131     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: The issue is occurring because you are trying to directly convert a pandas series to an integer, whereas you need to convert the "publication_date" (which I'm assuming is a string, but you would need to specify it as such) into an integer (using something like astype(int)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For speed up processing of datetime, you may have to convert it to datetime, then extract the year to make comparison.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'publication_date': ['10/05/1999', '15/12/2005', '23/09/2002', '05/03/2000', '18/07/2008']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['publication_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publication_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
# Fastest: due to it directly checks the condition publication_date year greater than or equal to 2000 for each element in the column and then sums up the True values
print(df["publication_date"].dt.year.ge(2000).sum())

# Slower a bit: filters the DataFrame based on the condition publication_date year greater than 2000 and then counts the number of rows in the filtered DataFrame.
print(df[df['publication_date'].dt.year > 2000].count())
```

Performance measurement:

```
import pandas as pd
import timeit as t

data = {'publication_date': ['10/05/1999', '15/12/2005', '23/09/2002', '05/03/2000', '18/07/2008']*100000}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['publication_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publication_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

time = t.timeit(stmt='df["publication_date"].dt.year.ge(2000).sum()', number=500, globals=globals())
print(time) # 13.602070399967488

time = t.timeit(stmt='df[df["publication_date"].dt.year > 2000].astype(bool).sum()', number=500, globals=globals())
print(time) # 16.904740899975877

time = t.timeit(stmt='df[df["publication_date"].dt.year > 2000].count()', number=500, globals=globals())
print(time) # 17.05563960003201
```

Comment: Note that slicing+count is not the most efficient, you can directly `sum` the boolean series ;)

Comment: Thanks @mozway, I have revised and added performance.

Answer (score 1):

First convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then get the year, compare to 2000 and sum:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["publication_date"], dayfirst=True).dt.year.ge(2000).sum()
```

Or compare to `2020-01-01`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["publication_date"], dayfirst=True).ge('2000-01-01').sum()
```

Or slice the year with [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) and convert with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df["publication_date"].str[-4:].astype(int).ge(2000).sum()
```